# Relation between time it takes for liquid to reach a height and flow rate in a frustum

Tags: calculus, related-rates

Suppose I have a physical coffee mug that is in the shape of a frustum. I can find the physical dimensions like smallest and largest radius and the height of the frustum. My question is how long in seconds will it take to reach any random height with a known flow rate. For example I may want to know how long it will take to fill the cup up to  2 inches, 5 inches, etc in a cup 8 inches tall with say a 4 cubic inch flow rate of water?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: It's somewhat odd to describe the flow rate as 4 cubic inches rather than 4 cubic inches per second or per minute or per some-specified unit of time. If it's 4 cubic inches per minute, then the time it will take is the volume divided by 4 cubic inches per minute. So if the volume is 100 cubic inches then the time is $100/4 = 25$ minutes. $\qquad$

Comment: $$ \frac{100 \text{ cubic inches}}{4 \text{ cubic inches per minute}} = 25 \text{minutes}. $$

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the frustum of a cone. One would need the radius at the bottom, the radius at the top, and the height from bottom to top.

Comment: Yes 4 cubic inches per minute flow rate. And  yes it is a frustum of a cone. A cylinder would be an easy solution. Lets say the larger radius of the frustum is 4 inches and the smaller bottom radius is only 1 inch.  This odd size cup is still only 8 inches tall. With a constant flow rate above, the time it takes the water level to get to any level will be a  varying slowing rate. I wish to calculate the time it would take to get to any water level in the cup with this constant flow rate

Comment: Similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626218 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366845

Comment: Those similar solutions are interesting but haven't solved the problem. What I am looking for is a time function. That is, if I start filling this large cup at a rate of 4 cubic inches per minute, when (that is how many seconds) will the water level reach any arbitrary height?

Comment: I found one non elegant solution. Take the frustum and convert it to a cone. factor out the radius so the cone formula is only in terms of volume vs cone height. Calculate the cone volume and fill time with selected flow rate.Then subtract out the cone tip volume and cone tip fill time from the above to get the original frustum fill height vs fill time.

Comment: I would still like to find a direct way to use the frustum formula without having to construct and then de construct a cone. If the frustum formula could be reduced to only volume vs height without the two radii as variables, that might be a route. Just looking to get a formula that plugs in the frustum two radii, the frustum height and the flow rate in then outputs a time when I select a water level in the frustum.

Comment: Got the solution. In the above case the time it takes is 43.976 sec to fill the entire 8 inch tall bucket. To get the time at any height up to 8 inches is the formula T= 5.497 h  That is in this particular bucket dimension.